# autonum with subequations

Tags: autonum

Is there a way to make the package *autonum* work with subequations? In the following example, the reference will correctly read eq. 1, but no number is appended to the equations (I would like to see 1a, 1b).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:subequations}
    \begin{align}
        1 + 1 = 2, \\
        2 + 2 = 4
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Let us examine \cref{eq:subequations}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was interesting. I believe I have a working solution making use of the `appto` command from the `etoolbox` package. Note that it is recommended to load the `hyperref` package with `hypertexnames=false` when using `autonum` (I have also chosen to use the `hidelinks` option).

The `autonum` package will only generate an equation number when that equation is actually referenced, so we need a way of referencing all of the equations in a subequations environment when that environment is referenced in a silent manner. We can do this by defining our own reference command that takes a label and does nothing, but then tell the autonum package that it is reference command with the `\autonum@generatePatchedReference` macro provided by the package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false, hidelinks]{hyperref} % hypertexnames=false for autonum compatibility (autonum.pdf 3.2 Hyperref)
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % \appto (etoolbox.pdf 3.3 Hook management)
\newcommand\toplabel[2]{% Args: macro and label for subequations environment
\appto{#1}{(\ref{#2})}%
}
\newcommand\sublabel[2]{% Args: macro and label for a subequation
\appto{#1}{\hoaxref{#2}}% Pretend to reference this equation when #1 is called, to fool autonum
}
\newcommand\hoaxref[1]{%
% Do nothing!
}
\makeatletter
\autonum@generatePatchedReference{hoaxref} % Tell autonum about our reference command (autonum.pdf 3.3 Reference commands)
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:1}
    \begin{align}
        1 + 1 &= 2 \label{eq:1a}\\
        2 + 2 &= 4\label{eq:1b}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\toplabel{\referone}{eq:1}%
\sublabel{\referone}{eq:1a}%
\sublabel{\referone}{eq:1b}%

Let us examine system \referone. 
\begin{subequations}
    \label{eq:2}
    \begin{align}
        3 + 3 &= 8 \label{eq:2a}\\
        4 + 4 &= 8\label{eq:2b}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

For comparison, an ordinary reference to system \ref{eq:2}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Usage note: Label the subequations environment equations in the usual way. Then, below this environment, setup a macro to reference the environment with `\toplabel{\myMacroName}{subeq:label}` and then `\sublabel{\myMacroName}{a:sub:equation}` for each subequation you wish to have numbered (this doesn't have to be all of them!). Here `\myMacroName` is what you will use to reference the subequation environment, as shown in the example.